# How to install Oracle Java web plugin on Chrome in 12.04?

Tags: java, google-chrome, oracle

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I install Sun/Oracle’s proprietary Java 6/7 JRE or JDK?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/56104/how-can-i-install-sun-oracles-proprietary-java-6-7-jre-or-jdk)

I've tried a whole lot of guides, but at best I ended up with neither Google Chrome not Firefox registering the Java plugin.

I specifically **do not need OpenJDK or IcedTea** - I need the Sun/Oracle version. The reason being is that http://www.gaikai.com does not support anything different.

Does anyone have any tips on getting it working?