# Download jdk 1.6 using wget

Tags: java, downloads, wget

I'm trying to get JDK 1.6 using the following command:

```
wget 'http://download.oracle.com/otn/java/jdk/6u14-b08/jdk-6u14-linux-x64.bin'
```

The download fails and I suspect it's related to the fact that the website requires you to accept the license agreement. Is there a way to accept the agreement and receive the file?

Comment: I assume that you are tying to install the oracle version of Java instead of the **IcedTea JDK** version that the software center installs? if so I can post an easier way to do that.....

Comment: The assumption is correct...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will go ahead and post it just in case....**Please note however that these instruciton install Java7 NOT Java6**

cut and paste from [http://www.webupd8.org](http://www.webupd8.org/2012/04/things-to-tweak-after-installing-ubuntu.html)

> Install Oracle Java 7
>
> For most stuff, OpenJDK/JRE is enough (and you can install it using
>   Ubuntu Software Center), but in case you really need Oracle
>   (previously Sun) Java 7, you can install it (this will install JDK/JRE
>   and the browser plugin) in Ubuntu using the WebUpd8 Java PPA
>
> in terminal type
>
> ```
> sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java
> sudo apt-get update
> sudo apt-get install oracle-java7-installer
> ```

This is a excerpt of my answer to [this](https://askubuntu.com/q/151539/65969) question.

The PPA that you install with thesecommands only points to the Java website to make installing easier, it does not contain Java itself. Oracle changed the license and now it can not be hosted anywhere  and can only be downloaded directly from Oracle..

[HERE](http://www.webupd8.org/2012/01/install-oracle-java-jdk-7-in-ubuntu-via.html) is an older post from the same site that gives more information on this change as well as more information on Java7 itself and how to remove it , check for and select which version is running.

- [Are PPA's safe to add to my system and what are some "red flags" to watch out for?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/35629/are-ppas-safe-to-add-to-my-system-and-what-are-some-red-flags-to-watch-out)

Comment: I like this approach where there's no need for a browser. Is there a way to do this for an RPM?

Comment: Sorry, ignore the RPM question. Just discovered that nowadays the JDK is already compiled so it just requires extraction.

Comment: I had luck getting 1.6 using `sudo apt-get install oracle-java6-installer`.  This worked even when the Oracle JDK archive site was giving me 404s or 410s.

Answer (score 0):

If you accept the agreement once you can then use the `--load-cookies FILE` option to `wget` to get it to use the saved cookie (e.g. from your .mozilla folder) to do the download. I don't see another way of doing it.

So

1. Accept the agreement in Firefox
2. Use `wget --load-cookies ~/.mozilla/firefox/XXXX.default/cookies.txt URL`

**Caveat**

Only works with old firefox cookies store - not the new sqlite backend.

**Alternative**

Alternatively you can install the Sun JDK from the repos as
TrailRider hinted at - the license agreement is done during the install.

Comment: _"from the repos as TrailRider hinted at"_ I did not post it as it was not really an answer to the question that was asked, I posted it anyway it can get downvoted if someone wants to nitpick I guess.

Comment: @TrailRider: I agree - I mentioned it as an alternative because using `wget` may not be possible anyway. The OP seems to be happy with using repos anyway.